# Get value of each comma separated ID from another table in Web Api-not working in live

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-4

I have a 'Skill' table where i store skills. And in 'Job' table i store all required skill when post job like UpWork. Employeers have checkbox to select all required skills. But i store skillID like: 1,5,6,8 in job table. When i retrieve the job details, i want to get name of the all skills because i want to show SkillName with other details of the Job from job table. My Web Api:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/JobApi/BrowseJobs/")]
public object BrowseJobs()
{

    var skills = db.Skills.ToDictionary(d => d.SkillID, n => n.SkillName);

    var jobData = (from j in db.Jobs where j.Preference==2
                   //from cj in j.ClosedJobs.DefaultIfEmpty() 
                   join cj in db.ClosedJobs.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   on j.JobID equals cj.JobID into closedJob
                   where !closedJob.Any()
                   join c in db.Categories on j.Category equals c.CategoryID

                   join jobContract in
                       (
                           from appliedJob in db.AppliedJobs.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           from offer in appliedJob.JobOffers.DefaultIfEmpty() 
                           from contract in db.Contracts.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           select new { appliedJob, offer, contract }
                           ).DefaultIfEmpty()
                   on j.JobID equals jobContract.appliedJob.JobID into jobContracts
                   where !jobContracts.Any(jobContract => jobContract.contract.CompletedDate != null)

                   select new
                   {

                       JobTitle = j.JobTitle,
                       JobID = j.JobID,
                       ReqSkillCommaSeperated = j.ReqSkill,
                       Category = c.CategoryName,
                       Budget=j.Budget,
                       Deadline=j.Deadline, 
                       JobDetails=j.JobDetails,
                       PublishDate=j.PublishDate,
                       TotalApplied=(from ap in db.AppliedJobs where j.JobID == ap.JobID select ap.AppliedJobID).DefaultIfEmpty().Count()

                   }).AsEnumerable()
        .Select(x => new
        {
            JobID = x.JobID,
            JobTitle = x.JobTitle,
            Category = x.Category,
            Budget = x.Budget,
            Deadline = x.Deadline,
            JobDetails = x.JobDetails,
            PublishDate = x.PublishDate,
            SkillNames = GetSkillName(x.ReqSkillCommaSeperated, skills),
            TotalApplied = (from ap in db.AppliedJobs where x.JobID == ap.JobID select ap.AppliedJobID).DefaultIfEmpty().Count()
        }).ToList();


    return jobData.AsEnumerable();
}



private string GetSkillName(string reqSkill, Dictionary<int, string> skills)
{
    if (reqSkill == null) return string.Empty;
    var skillArr = reqSkill.Split(',');
    var skillNameList = skillArr.Select(skillId => skills[Convert.ToInt32(skillId)])
                                .ToList();
    return String.Join(",", skillNameList);
}
```

[image]
[image]
My Problem is that the code is working well in my VS 2013. But when i uploaded it on a Godaddy live server, it doesn't work! returns 500 internal server error
Now i want to Make a SQL query instead of Linq. Can i do SQL with my desired result?

===================Edited=====================

your sql code is well worked. But i have others condition to be put on.
1. I need to show those job which is not closed yet (ClosedJobs table take the closed jobs ID).If a job ID is found on ClosedJobs table, it will not return in the list.

```
join cj in db.ClosedJobs.DefaultIfEmpty()
               on j.JobID equals cj.JobID into closedJob
               where !closedJob.Any()
```

2. Those job which is not found on Contracts table(Contracts table take the jobID of a job that is started as contract)

**2nd Edit===================**

```
 join jobContract in
                   (
                       from appliedJob in db.AppliedJobs.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       from offer in appliedJob.JobOffers.DefaultIfEmpty() 
                       from contract in db.Contracts.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       select new { appliedJob, offer, contract }
                       ).DefaultIfEmpty()
               on j.JobID equals jobContract.appliedJob.JobID into jobContracts
               where !jobContracts.Any(jobContract => jobContract.contract.CompletedDate != null)
```

EXP: `Job` table has relation with `AppliedJobs` table. `AppliedJobs` table has relation with JobOffers. `JobOffers` has relation with `Contracts`.
i don't want to show those jobs that are completed.(`Contracts.CompletedDate != null`). When a contract starts the field `CompletedDate` is set to null. After completing the contract ,it is changed null to the completed date.

**Where i will apply the condition?**

How can i do that? Can you help me? @John Cappelletti

Answer (score 1):

> **EDIT - Removed OUTER APPLY**

Below is a simple example of using `Stuff()` and `XML`.  If the sequence is important, then we must split the string first.

To be clear `@Skills` and `@YourData` are table variables and simply demonstrative.

**Example**

```
Declare @Skills table (SkillID int,SkillName varchar(50))
Insert Into @Skills values
 (1,'ASP')
,(2,'JavaScript')
,(3,'AngularJS')
,(4,'WordPress')
,(5,'Joomla')

Declare @YourData table (ID int,ReqSkill varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourData values
 (1,'2,3,4,5,1')
,(2,'3')
,(3,'3,4,5,2')
,(4,null)

Select A.ID
      ,Skills = Stuff((Select ',' +SkillName 
                        From  @Skills 
                        Where charindex(concat(',',SkillID,','),','+A.ReqSkill+',')>0
                        For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')
 From  @YourData A
 -- Your WHERE Statement Here --
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Skills
1   ASP,JavaScript,AngularJS,WordPress,Joomla
2   AngularJS
3   JavaScript,AngularJS,WordPress,Joomla
4   NULL
```

Comment: "
Select j.Deadline ,j.Budget,j.Category
      ,Skills =B.String
 From  Job j
 Outer Apply (
                Select String = Stuff((Select ',' +SkillName 
                                        From Skill 
                                        Where charindex(concat(',',SkillID,','),','+j.ReqSkill+',')>0
                                        For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')

              ) B" it works.  But where i will put my other condition? See edited part of the post. @John Cappelletti

Comment: it works! Can you please explain the Skills ,second in select?

Comment: @Fawel I don't understand the question in the 2nd edit